# How to get radio button checked using each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to get total price after user check on one of the radio button option. Whenever user click on radio button it's will loop all checked radio button and sum all to get final total. But the problem is the total is always wrong.

```
 // Radio Option
 $('label.radio_label').on('click', function () {

     var total = 0;

     $('.parent_radio_option input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function (index) {

         var radio_option = $(this).data('price');
         total += parseInt(radio_option);

         console.log(radio_option);

     });

     console.log('total: ' + total);
 });
```

You can try here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi46/vovpttym/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the click of the `label` is fired the checked status of the `input` element is not yet changed so you will always get the previously checked input element's value.

You need to use the change event of the radio

```
$('.parent_radio_option input[type="radio"]').on('change', function () {})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi46/vovpttym/1/)